# Homestead: downgrade to MySQL 5.6 by reinstalling the box

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, homestead

I've just set up my local environment based on the latest Homestead box. The box comes with **MySQL 5.7**, which causes various problems with my migrations. The migrations were working fine on **MySQL 5.6**.

Now, the production server uses 5.6, so (instead of adjusting all the failing migration queries) I would like to downgrade my local MySQL to version 5.6, to get the localhost working.

Obviously, this can be done via `vagrant ssh` (manual downgrade). However, I was thinking, **is there a way to reinstall the Homestead box using an older version that uses MySQL 5.6?**

Note:

Surely, some of you will suggest getting the queries right for version 5.7 in case of possible upgrade on production server. **I also consider that.** But currently I just want to know how do I get my hands the on older Homestead versions.

Answer (score 3):

The last version of the Homestead VM to use MySQL 5.6 was v0.2.7. To use this box, you should use Homestead version 2.2.1.

Additionally, you'll want to run the following commands to install the correct box:

```
vagrant box remove laravel/homestead
vagrant box add laravel/homestead --box-version 0.2.7
```

Comment: Thanks. I ran both commands, Homestead is on version 0.2.7. However, the MySQL version is unchained. PhpMyAdmin shows 5.7, Homestead's shell confirms it. Is there any other command I need to run, so the older Homestead version "clicked in"? Do I need to restart some services? Also, `composer install` claims there's nothing to install or update, even if I just reinstalled the box. Ideas?

Comment: Plus, just read the answer again, and first you write about Homestead's version `2.2.1`, but the command adds `0.2.7`. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The `--box-version 0.2.7` is the vagrant box you need.  `2.2.1` is the composer dependency that uses a box less than 0.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute this command inside vagrant:

```
apt-get install -y mysql-server-5.6
```

After this, mysql version will be 5.6